# C# DateTime to String Issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I feel like this is something I've done a thousand times so not sure why it is being so difficult now.  I've created a method that simply returns Today's date for the user based on their UTC offset.  But instead of returning a string resembling a date, it is returning this garbage

```
"䙭/䙭/Ἰ뻱䙭"
```

Here is the code.

```
public string getToday(Context context)
{
    var settings = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    var offset = settings.GetInt("offset", -5);
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offset);

    return now.ToShortDateString();
}
```

When I step into the code using a breakpoint, offset and now both seem correct.  now contains valid date parts all appearing to be accurate.  Something about converting now to a string seems to go horribly wrong.  Also tried:

```
return now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Same result.  Weird part is the below code in another activity works without issue

```
var offset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).Hours;
var now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offset);
now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: What culture is this code running under?

Comment: @Zenexer - I'd say that's a given. My comment was more of a pointer to the OP.

Comment: @Oded Yeah, my reply was just meant to be humorous.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea.  I've never dealt with globalization as I only develop for US applications.  But I can tell you that the code that generates a valid date is in the same project as the code I am having an issue with.  So I doubt whatever the issue is stems for a project or solution level setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your device is set to a Chinese/Japanese/Korean culture. If you always want to return US dates, use:

```
return now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edit**: Given the rest of your comments, I’m starting to suspect that this *might* be caused by corruption, or by a bug in the MonoDroid implementation. You could try working around it by constructing the date manually (although this admittedly doesn’t address the *cause* of your issue):

```
return string.Format("{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:0000}", now.Month, now.Day, now.Year);
```

Comment: He said other applications worked, so it sounds application-specific--not machine-specific--to me.  In this case, he should investigate to see where the culture is incorrectly set within his application, rather than fixing it on a per-case basis.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.  I've never had this problem before and have never had to worry about globalization.  The code that returns a valid DateTime is within the exact same project.

Comment: Are you sure the garbage is being returned by your method, and is not being converted to it by the code calling your method (for example, upon saving to file)? It seems that your first symbol, ‘䙭’, means “to lift or raise (one’s dress, skirt, etc.)”; barely related to dates/times.

Comment: Try assigning the result of executing `now.ToShortDateString()` to a local string variable before returning it; then use a breakpoint to check its value within the debugger.

Comment: I'm sure.  Originally the code included a string variable that returned the date string.  string today = now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); return today;  When stepping through the method, today's value in the Locals window shows the same thing.

Comment: Your workaround seems to do the trick.  Wish I could've figured out the cause although I'm seeing MonoDroid seems to be a very buggy, unstable product so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like a localization issue.  Make sure you're actually in English, be it en-US or similar.